# No such file or directory found, image path to file

Tags: java, android, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, upload

I have a nexus 5 with android 5.0.
I want to send an image to amazon s3 but I get this error:

```
11-27 11:29:52.687  21423-21423/com.laurenswuyts.witpa E/Upload to amazons3﹕ com.amazonaws.AmazonClientException: Unable to calculate MD5 hash: /document/image:2810: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
            at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.putObject(Unknown Source)
            at com.amazonaws.mobileconnectors.s3.transfermanager.internal.UploadCallable.uploadInOneChunk(Unknown Source)
            at com.amazonaws.mobileconnectors.s3.transfermanager.internal.UploadCallable.call(Unknown Source)
            at com.amazonaws.mobileconnectors.s3.transfermanager.internal.UploadMonitor.upload(Unknown Source)
            at com.amazonaws.mobileconnectors.s3.transfermanager.internal.UploadMonitor.call(Unknown Source)
            at com.amazonaws.mobileconnectors.s3.transfermanager.internal.UploadMonitor.call(Unknown Source)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
     Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /document/image:2810: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
            at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:456)
            at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:76)
            at com.amazonaws.util.Md5Utils.computeMD5Hash(Unknown Source)
            at com.amazonaws.util.Md5Utils.md5AsBase64(Unknown Source)
            at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.putObject(Unknown Source)
            at com.amazonaws.mobileconnectors.s3.transfermanager.internal.UploadCallable.uploadInOneChunk(Unknown Source)
            at com.amazonaws.mobileconnectors.s3.transfermanager.internal.UploadCallable.call(Unknown Source)
            at com.amazonaws.mobileconnectors.s3.transfermanager.internal.UploadMonitor.upload(Unknown Source)
            at com.amazonaws.mobileconnectors.s3.transfermanager.internal.UploadMonitor.call(Unknown Source)
            at com.amazonaws.mobileconnectors.s3.transfermanager.internal.UploadMonitor.call(Unknown Source)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
     Caused by: android.system.ErrnoException: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
            at libcore.io.Posix.open(Native Method)
            at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.open(BlockGuardOs.java:186)
            at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:442)
            at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:76)
            at com.amazonaws.util.Md5Utils.computeMD5Hash(Unknown Source)
            at com.amazonaws.util.Md5Utils.md5AsBase64(Unknown Source)
            at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.putObject(Unknown Source)
            at com.amazonaws.mobileconnectors.s3.transfermanager.internal.UploadCallable.uploadInOneChunk(Unknown Source)
            at com.amazonaws.mobileconnectors.s3.transfermanager.internal.UploadCallable.call(Unknown Source)
            at com.amazonaws.mobileconnectors.s3.transfermanager.internal.UploadMonitor.upload(Unknown Source)
            at com.amazonaws.mobileconnectors.s3.transfermanager.internal.UploadMonitor.call(Unknown Source)
            at com.amazonaws.mobileconnectors.s3.transfermanager.internal.UploadMonitor.call(Unknown Source)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

So I have a button where you can select an image from your phone:

```
 //When clicked on addimage
        addImage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // To open up a gallery browser
                Intent intent = new Intent();
                intent.setType("image/*");
                intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Picture"), PICK_IMAGE);
            }
        });

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if (requestCode == PICK_IMAGE && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK && null != data) {
            uri = data.getData();

//create file of image to upload
            images3 = new File(uri.getPath());
        }
    }
```

I get the error at the line = images3 = new File(uri.getPath());

To get the full code of my upload to amazon s3:

```
TransferManager transferManager = new TransferManager(credentialsProvider);

                    try {
                        mUpload = transferManager.upload(
                                "witpalol",
                                "image.jpg",
                                images3);
                        mUpload.waitForCompletion();
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        Log.e("Upload to amazons3", "", e);
                    }
```

But the problem is I can't get the file ...
Anybody have a solution for this?

**EDIT**

I tried to get the full path of the uri:

```
// And to convert the image URI to the direct file system path of the image file
public String getRealPathFromURI(Uri contentUri) {

    // can post image
    String [] proj={MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};
    Cursor cursor = getActivity().getContentResolver().query(contentUri,
            proj, // Which columns to return
            null,       // WHERE clause; which rows to return (all rows)
            null,       // WHERE clause selection arguments (none)
            null); // Order-by clause (ascending by name)
    int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
    cursor.moveToFirst();

    return cursor.getString(column_index);
}
```

So images3 = new File(getRealPathFromURI(uri));

But then I get this error on that line:

```
11-27 11:55:18.872  23286-23286/com.laurenswuyts.witpa E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.laurenswuyts.witpa, PID: 23286
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=65537, result=-1, data=Intent { dat=content://com.android.providers.media.documents/document/image:2810 flg=0x1 }} to activity {com.laurenswuyts.witpa/com.laurenswuyts.witpa.Activities.Events.AddEventActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'char[] java.lang.String.toCharArray()' on a null object reference
            at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3539)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3582)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1300(ActivityThread.java:144)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1327)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'char[] java.lang.String.toCharArray()' on a null object reference
            at java.io.File.fixSlashes(File.java:185)
            at java.io.File.<init>(File.java:134)
            at com.laurenswuyts.witpa.Fragments.Events.AddEventFragment.decodeUri(AddEventFragment.java:254)
            at com.laurenswuyts.witpa.Fragments.Events.AddEventFragment.onActivityResult(AddEventFragment.java:213)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onActivityResult(FragmentActivity.java:163)
            at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:6135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3535)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3582)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1300(ActivityThread.java:144)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1327)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
```

Comment: `uri.getPath()`. Please tell us which path that is exactly. Is it `/document/image:2810`? That is no file system path. You first have to convert it to a file path before File class can handle it.

Comment: Uri = data.getData() => uri.getPath() is indeed /document/image:2810

Comment: You are not the first with this issue. In fact everybody meets it. I have no code at hand at the moment. Google/search for 'convert gallery/mediastore path to file path'.

Comment: Yes you have added code and edited your question posting new logcat with a a new `NullPointerException`. You should have told that you have one. Now what is null?